# How to get latch with blocking assignment?

Tags: system-verilog, vivado

My question emphases the amend of the struct's element!

```
struct packed {
    logic        word;
    logic [31:0] test;
} a;
logic [32:0] a_input;
logic a_ff;

always_latch begin
  if (enable) begin
    a = a_input;          // map the bus `a_input` to the struct `a`
    a.test = a.test[1:0]; // change the `test` child
  end
end
```

[image: wavedrom]

- `enable` and `a_input` are flip-flops on the same clock (then can reach the latch at different moment in physical hardware)
- `a` is the modified comb/latch version of `a_input`

Vivado doesn't synthetize this as a latch.

I want to change only the `a.test`, `a_input` isn't a struct then I can't use `a_input.test`. Then that code describes well what I want to do.

**How can I get a latch?**

**Edit:** I can use a mix of `always_comb`, `always_ff` and `assign`.

```
struct packed {
    logic        word;
    logic [31:0] test;
} a, a_comb;
logic [32:0] a_input;
logic a_ff;

always_ff @(posedge clk)
  if (enable) begin
    a_ff <= a_comb;
end
always_comb begin
  a_comb = a_input;               // map the bus `a_input` to the struct `a_comb`
  a_comb.test = a_comb.test[1:0]; // change the `test` child
end
assign a = (enable)? a_comb: a_ff;
```

I'd like to avoid these extra lines and temporary logics, it should be possible using a simple `always_latch`.

**Edit #2:**

I really want to amend **only** the `test` element of my struct, and let all the other element being assigned from `a_input`.

If it was a FF, it'd do:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk)
  if (enable) begin
    a      <= a_input;     // map the bus `a_input` to the struct `a`
    a.test <= a.test[1:0]; // change the `test` child
  end
end
```

I want to convert that logic to a latch instead of FF.

Comment: in order for it to be treated as a non-latch, vivado should optimize away the 'enable' signal. So, i guess we need more info about how it is evaluated. Also, use **non-blocking** assignments in the latch.

Comment: If it is not synthesizing as a latch, what is it synthesizing to? FYI `a.test[31:2]` will always synthesize to a constant. It will not make a difference for synthesis but **non-blocking** assignments is recommenced for latches (reduces chance of race condition in RTL simulation).

Comment: It's synthesized as a LUT with an infinite loopback. Changing to non-blocking, the wire is defined as unconnected.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure a simple latch will synthesize as a latch. If it doesn't, then that a separate problem and you will need to figure out; check your synthesizer version and target device.

```
always_latch
  if (enable)
    a <= a_input;
```

I'm not sure why your latch does not work. Latches should be kept simple to prevent unintended complex feedback. Your code looks simple enough as the only thing it is doing beyond a basic D-latch is mask some bits.

Assuming the basic latch synthesizes correctly, you can do combinational logic before or after the latch. Ex:

```
always_comb begin
  a_comb = a_input;
  a_comb.test = a_comb.test[1:0];
end
always_latch
  if (enable)
    a <= a_comb;
```

or:

```
always_latch
  if (enable)
    a_lat <= a_input;
always_comb begin
  a = a_lat;
  a.test = a.test[1:0];
end
```

If you are only masking bits, you should be able to use:

```
always_latch
  if (enable)
    a <= a_input & 32'h100000003;
```

If the above three doesn't work, but a simple latch does work properly, then it might be optimization related. In this case make sure `a_input` and `enable` are FF and are functionally toggleable (ie not optimized away due do something else upstream). Also check how `a` is begin used down stream.

Comment: The question was about how to get this to work inside a single always_latch with blocking assignment. I'm sure your method will work (and is probably better), but I'm still curious as to why the OP's original code didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this code in vivado, it able to synthesize it to LDCE latch .

```
   module latch (
        input  logic  a_input,enable,
        output logic  a
    );

        always_latch if(enable) a = a_input;

    endmodule
```

Comment: That's different from what I explained. You have a single assignment in your `always_latch`, blocking or non-blocking doesn't make any difference in your code.

Answer (score -1):

A latch is effectively a level sensitive register rather than edge sensitive. The driver of enable isn't shown, so that may be getting driven to 0 by Vivado.   A quick example, if you are trying to make a latch the following would should do it.

```
always@(enable) begin
   a = enable ? a_input : a;
end
```

Generally, we tend to want to avoid latches, but if you are dead set on making one, you can start by getting rid of the `posedge clk` from the sensitivity list and changing it to `*`.  That would mean that on any change of the signals, you would get a re-evaluation of the block.   The fact that enable would control loading of the a_ff term while high, and then hold the value while low, should be seen as a latch provided that enable is driven from some source and not optimized to a constant 0 state because it is a undriven signal.

Comment: Your answer is exactly same as the Rama Krishna Meda's one using Verilog2001 instead of SV. The 2nd line (struct's element amend) isn't present in your example and that is what bother me.